# PHPUnit keeps reporting that Selenium Server is inactive despite server is running

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, selenium-ide

I have no idea why PHPUnit keeps saying :

```
The Selenium Server is not active on host http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub at port 4444.
```

I started my Selenium Server from my desktop through this command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
```

And I got this log:

[image]

There are a couple of drivers not registered. I don't know why, but I was just following the very brief installation guide on SeleniumHQ's website.

Next, I started to try running a PHPUnit test script which I generated from Selenium IDE and exported it as a `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTest2Case`. Here's how my setup code looks:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setHost('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub');
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://localhost/testing");
  }
```

I went on to run PHPUnit on this script in verbose mode, but I have no idea why it keeps saying :

```
The Selenium Server is not active on host http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub at port 4444.
```

I can access `http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub` through my browser without problem. So, I'm pretty sure that my Selenium server is already running.

PHPUnit keeps terminating with this result:

```
OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Skipped: 1.
```

What else do I've to do to get PHPUnit and Selenium to work?

Comment: Just a guess here but `setHost` makes me think you should only be passing a hostname, ie `this->setHost('127.0.0.1')` or even discard the host, port, etc as they are probably ok with the defaults

Comment: Yup, those are the defaults ~ https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/phpunit.xml.dist

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using selenium 3 with PHP 5.5.9 on ubuntu.

Comment: you can also add --verbose to phpunit running, to get more info.

Answer (score -1):

`setHost()` should have only the host part

```
$this->setHost('127.0.0.1');
```

Apart from that I would suggest using simple PHPUnit, PageObjects and a slightly more active/maintained WebDriver wrapper like [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) as it will allow you to better handle/integrate with cross-browser testing providers as BrowserStack.
But that's just my opinion :)

Comment: I have tried using only the host part in setHost() but I'm still getting the same error. It seems like it couldn't reach the Selenium server at all.

Comment: sorry, what I meant is that `setHost` should have only the IP, you will also need the `setPort` and others

Comment: I know what your meant. I have tried that but it still doesn't work. I actually put in that path because localhost:4444 actually gives me a 403 error when accessed through the browser. But I can access it through the browser with the wd/hub/ path.

Comment: best thing would be to see what's the exact error  (print_r?) being thrown at `phpunit-selenium-master/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:298`

Comment: this has nothing to do with the problem. I have the same problem and I don't use that.